# Gnum/Ubuntu Boot Manager Not Showing In Boot Menu On Bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had windows 10 on my ssd. I participated 55gb free space and installed Ubuntu on this. 500mb efi participation, 10gb for swap, 20gb for root and 20 gb for home. I installed successfully. But when boot my laptop, it boots to windows boot manager automatically and not showing me Grub (I didn't install ubuntu along side windows so this is normal). When go bios/boot priority, there is no Grub/Ubuntu boot manager. I can't set grub for first/default option. But If I go boot menu on startup, I can see Ubuntu. What should I do to make Ubuntu as my first/default boot option?

[Bios Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8PxQ.jpg)

[Boot Priority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1aSU.jpg)

[Boot Menu On Startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhi6p.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually didn't make a boot partition, that's why ubuntu didn't install GRUB bootloader.

First **backup your important files.**

Now second, you should create a partition for /boot, recommended size is 512MB. To create a partition open **GParted** and create a the /boot partition, give it the size 512MB.

then after you create the partition type these commands.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX 
sudo grub-update
```

/dev/sdX is the partition you created

I wish that helps you :).